# Canvas draws distorted figures and text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm building a simple Chart using Canvas. (All the custom packages out there do not fit my needs).

On the very basic step of development I've got into a distorted effect of everything I try to draw. I've been lurking the forum for answers and I don't have CSS rules applied to canvas tag.

HTML:

```
 <div id="platform-wrapper">
     <canvas id="platform-chart" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#platform-wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

JS:

```
;(function() {
var PlatformChart = function() {
    var graph,
        canvas,
        ctx,
        xPadding = 30,
        yPadding = 30,
        data = { values:[
            { X: "16:13:15", Y: 1.23453 },
            { X: "16:13:30", Y: 1.24528 },
            { X: "16:13:45", Y: 1.23438 },
            { X: "16:14:00", Y: 1.34544 },
            { X: "16:14:15", Y: 1.53444 }
        ]};

    function getMaxY() {
        var max = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i ++) {
            if(data.values[i].Y > max) {
                max = data.values[i].Y;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }

    function getXPixel(val) {
        return ((graph.width() - xPadding) / data.values.length) * val + (xPadding * 1.5);
    }

    function getYPixel(val) {
        return graph.height() - (((graph.height() - yPadding) / getMaxY()) * val) - yPadding;
    }

    return {
        init: function(canvasId) {
            var selector = '#'+canvasId;

            if (!canvasId || !$(selector).length) return false;

            graph = $(selector);
            canvas = graph[0];
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            return this;
        },

        config: function(config) {
            for(var prop in config) {
                if (ctx.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    ctx[prop] = config[prop];
                }
            }

            return this;
        },

        drawBase: function() {
            //ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            //ctx.fillStyle = "#4c88e1";
            //ctx.fill();
            return this;
        },

        clear: function() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            return this;
        },

        drawX: function(offset) {
            //ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

            for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i ++) {
                ctx.fillText(data.values[i].X, getXPixel(i) + xPadding - 20, graph.height() - 10);
            }

            return this;
        },

        drawY: function(offset) {
            ctx.textAlign = "right";
            //ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            //ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

            for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i ++) {
                ctx.fillText(data.values[i].Y, graph.width() - 10, getYPixel(i) - yPadding);
            }

            return this;
        }
    }
};

    window.platformChart = new PlatformChart();
}());
```

Init via console:

```
platformChart.init('platform-chart').config({lineWidth:2, strokeStyle:'#333', textAlign: 'center'}).drawBase().drawX().drawY()
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz03dsbn/)

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If yes, that may be the answer to your unexpected distortion.  Bootstrap uses CSS to resize your columns. This causes your canvas to be resized using CSS. Resizing a canvas with CSS distort the canvas content because the content is stretched to fit the new CSS size.

Comment: I've disabled Bootstrap in JSFiddle, same issue. Did you tried to open it?

Comment: Yep, I did look at the fiddle, but it wasn't helpful. The chart appears incomplete (I see the legends but no actual chart). The legends don't appear distorted in my device (win8.1/IE11,Chrome39,FF34). Offhand, I don't see anything in your code that would distort drawings. One possibility: Check that your getXPixel/getYPixel values are valid (not causing distortion). Otherwise, CSS is the likely cause.

Comment: Try `ctx.translate(0.5,0.5)` once before you draw. Check out here this [link](http://www.rgraph.net/docs/howto-get-crisp-lines-with-no-antialias.html)